# how to display photos to the view based on eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two table: user_details and photos table I have successfully stored an image(file_name,file_path) and the user_id(fk) to the photos table and I made some relationships on them.

Photo.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'photos';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','file_name','file_size','file_mime','file_path','created_by'];

    public function user_details(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User_Detail');
    }
}
```

User_Detail.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User_Detail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_details';
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','address', 'user_id', 'age','dob];

    public function user_details(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User_Detail');
    }
}
```

Now i want to display all the user_details in the table and the respective image of each.

```
  public function getUserInformation(){
    $user= $this->UserRepository->getUserInformation();
    $details= $this->user_detail->photo->get()->all();
    return view('admin.show-user', compact('user','details'));
  }
```

I want to call on that photo method but I simply can't. I'm really new to eloquent. Also how can i loop them and display them one by one in every row. like this[image]

This is what my db looks like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwCqS.png)

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you please explain me that on lay man's terms I am new to this

Comment: The accepted answer is (IMHO) quite thorough. If you have a specific question in relation to any of the points made there, that cannot be addressed through googling, then I'd be happy to try to answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll make an effort to read it thoroughly. Thank you so much for this